# Is Guava RateLimiter thread-safe

Tags: guava, rate-limiting

Couldn't find definite answer via googling, stackoverflow search and on github as well about this, but is Guava RateLimiter thread-safe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is. Found it in source code.

https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/util/concurrent/RateLimiter.java#L41-L42